# Is MessageSourceAware a special case or can I inject other dependencies in a similar fashion?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Using Spring, one can define classes that implement [`MessageSourceAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSourceAware.html). The container will then inject a `MessageSource` automatically (*see the tail end of [this documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource)*).

Is this a special case or can I use this concept to inject other dependencies too? For instance, can my classes implement the following interface:

```
public interface MyServiceAware {
  void setMyService(MyService service);
}
```

and then somehow be auto-wired with a suitable bean?

*Note: I am using XML configuration exclusively at the moment and I'd be reluctant to move to Java-based annotations.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*Aware` interfaces are handled by a [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) that is automatically registered in the application context (`org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor`).

You could create and register your own postprocessor to handle `MyServiceAware` beans.

Remember also that the XML configuration does support [autowiring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire) for appropriately configured beans.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For future readers who are interested in implementing a `BeanPostProcessor`, see the `org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor` class, which is responsible for injecting the `MessageSource`.

Comment: In fact, I wrote a blog entry on [using marking interfaces in Spring](http://cryptonode.org/2013/03/using-marker-interfaces-in-spring/) that explains exactly how to do this.